# The equation of a curve is $y=x^3-8$. Find the equation of the normal to the curve at the point where the curve crosses the x-axis.

Tags: calculus

> The equation of a curve is $y=x^3-8$. Find the equation of the normal to the curve at the point where the curve crosses the x-axis.

So first I factorised the function:
$$x^3-8= (x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$$
Therefore it crosses the x-axis at $(2,0)$.

Secondly, I found the derivative of the function:
$$y' = 3x^2$$

Substituting $f '(2)=12$

Tangent's equation:
$$y=12x-24$$

So the normal equation would be:
$$y=-\frac 1{12}x+\frac 16$$

Is this answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done just fine! Your solutions are spot on.  Was there any point in your work that you were/are unsure about?

If you need to hand in your work to justify your solutions, I'd make sure to mention that the point of intersection of $y= x^3-8$ with $y=0$ is the solution to $$x^3-8=(x−2)(x^2+2x+4)= 0.$$  You are correct that the point of intersection is $(2, 0)$.

From there, clear sailing!

Comment: Just so I don't miss anything, I take it that your question was a "solution-verification" sort. Absolutely fine.  You seemed to present your work confidently, so my answer was primarily a verification answer.  Feel free to ask any specific questions about the process you went through to solve for the two equations of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since your normal passes through the point $(2,0)$ it is correct.

Comment: Will the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution for those knowing about the gradient of a function:

Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y$. The given curve is a level curve of $f$ ($f=8$).   Then $\nabla f(x,y) = 3x^2 \vec{i}-\vec{j}$ so the normal direction at the $x$-intercept $(2,0)$ is $\nabla f(2,0) = 12 \vec{i}-\vec{j}$.  So the line is parameterized as $\mathbf{r}(t)= 2\vec{i} + t\ (12 \vec{i}-\vec{j})=(2+12t) \vec{i}+(-t) \vec{j}$. Set $y=-t$ and thus $x=2-12y$ or (in standard form) $x+12y=2$. Solving for $y$ gives the slope-intercept form: $y=-\frac{1}{12}x+\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Please don't assume every school/university have the same classes. Most of the people who will be able to understand what you wrote, probabaly never had a class called "Calculus III".

Comment: That's why I wrote "For those who have had Calculus III" in the first line; those who have not had it can skip it.  Some readers of this question might have had multivariable Calculus or whatever it is called (Calc III is a pretty common course title). I'm sharing my knowledge. Take what you like and leave the rest. I never assumed that "every school/university have the same classes" but you assumed that I assumed so.  I'm not sure what you're so offended by.  But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Fixed the lead-in sentence so Fredrik would be happier.